# Mutually exclusive flags on file_put_contents?

Tags: php, file, locking, flags

On the [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file-put-contents)() documentation, it says the following:

**FILE_APPEND**:

> Mutually exclusive with LOCK_EX since
>   appends are atomic and thus there is
>   no reason to lock.

**LOCK_EX**:

> Mutually exclusive with FILE_APPEND.

Yet, a couple of lines bellow I see the following code:

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// The new person to add to the file
$person = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

So, are the FILE_APPEND and LOCK_EX flags mutually exclusive or not? If yes, why do they use it in the example? Is this a case of bad documentation?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Without looking too closely, sounds like whoever wrote the example wasn't familiar with the documentation.  Or maybe the API changed since the example was written, and nobody updated the example.

Comment: Thanks Mark, +1 I was starting to wonder if there was any obscure reason that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: This was correctly fixed for [bug #52767](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52767). The flags *are not* mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just bad documentation. The [manual clearly states](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

> `FILE_APPEND` : If file filename
> already exists, append the data to the
> file instead of overwriting it.
> Mutually exclusive with LOCK_EX since
> appends are atomic and thus there is
> no reason to lock.
>
> `LOCK_EX` : Acquire an exclusive lock
> on the file while proceeding to the
> writing. Mutually exclusive with
> FILE_APPEND.

And the example you speak of:

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// The new person to add to the file
$person = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

It looks like the person who coded the example misunderstood the meaning of 'mutually exclusive', *or* that produces some secret, undocumented bahaviour.

Comment: What does it mean?  'mutually exclusive'

Answer (score 4):

Like [@karim79 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315055/mutually-exclusive-flags-on-fileputcontents/1315058#1315058), this was an error in the manual : see [bug #49329](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49329), which I reported after seeing this question/answer, and has been corrected/closed a couple of minutes ago.

*(It will take some time to be reflected in the online version of the manual, but ahs been corrected in its sources)*